# How do I correctly setup my frustum projection?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to create a frustum projection so I can properly view 3D objects and navigate through 3D space. I know that a cone-type shape is created at 0,0,0 and you can specify which direction it goes, but there are a few things I don't understand:

What exactly do `nearClipPlane` and `farClipPlane` work? Why should the cone be further away?

How do I control the position and where the camera points?

I've seen people create frustums using only **1s** and **-1s**, is this the proper way?

My code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(windowWidth / 2, windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2, windowHeight / 2, 0, -50);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //draw

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend using the new [programmable pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview) instead of the old fixed-function pipeline, because it has been deprecated for more than ten years. First, the new one looks very difficult, but when you've understood the concept behind it, it is much simpler than the old pipeline.

> What exactly do nearClipPlane and farClipPlane work?

[image]
Objects, which are in front of the near clipping plane or in the back of the far clipping plane, won't get rendered.
You shouldn't pass negative values to `glFrustum()` for the near and the far plane, common values are 0.1 for the near plane and 100-1000 for the far plane distance.

> How do I control the position and where the camera points?

In OpenGL, you don't change the position of the camera, but you transform the whole scene (modelview-matrix) in the inversed direction. For example, if you want to set your camera's position to 10, 0, 5 and rotate your camera by 45 degrees around the y-axis, you have to use

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
/*
If you wouldn't generate a new identity matrix every frame, you would **add** the rotation/translation to the previous one, which obviously isn't what you want
*/
glLoadIdentity();
Vector3f cameraPosititon = new Vector3f(10, 0, 5);    

/*
rotate selected matrix about 45 degrees around y
With the 1 as third argument you select that you want to rotate over the y-axis.
If you would pass 1 as 2nd or 4th argument, you would rotate over the x or the z axis.*/
glRotatef(45, 0, 1, 0);
//translate selected matrix about x, y, z
glTranslatef(-1 * cameraPosition.x, -1 * cameraPosition.y, -1 * cameraPosition.z);
```

I have passed the position of the camera multiplied by -1, because you have to transform the whole scene in the inversed direction to get an effect that it looks like the camera is moving around.

Comment: Why does the near and far plane work like that? Wouldn't that mean you could see anything before or after the two planes?

Comment: No, it's different. It means that you can see anything between the two planes.

Comment: If that's the case why do people usually position the near plane clip far away from the camera?